# vmware server 1.9 on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vmware-server

I was using vmware server 1.9 in vista (32-bit) when i upgraded my host system to windows 7 (32-bit) and that's when everything went wrong.

first I was getting an error when start my virtual server (linux, centos)

> Virtual device Ethernet0 will start disconnected

but now it's even worse, when I try to start a new created virtual machine my windows freezes and I can't do anything anymore...

any help would be greatly appreciated

ps: I installed vmware server 1.9 because the teacher told us to work with that version.

Comment: So simply do not boot windows. Only boot your vmware-server and run your VMs.

Comment: @Hennes wow that's a very late reply. but thanks ... I guess

Comment: I am doing some tag cleanups (see meta site). Some vendor tags are now depracated. The tag [vmware] is one of them. If things were tagged both [vmware-server] and [vmware] I am removing the latter, and occasionally adding comments or answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely to find that Windows 7 is not a supported platform for VMWare Server 1.0.x as that OS did not exist until after is was superseded by VMWare Server 2.0.x.

(I assume you are meaning VMWare Server 1.0.9 - there wasn't a version 1.9 IIRC)

Comment: ah ok so I need to run the 2.0.x version?

Comment: Assuming that works OK in Windows 7, which is more likely, though check with your teacher in case you are expected to pass copies of your v2 created VMs to someone running v1.0.x as that might pose compatibility problems.